# java.sql.Statement#executeUpdate() vs execute()?

Tags: jdbc

If I don't care about the number of rows updated, is there any advantage gained by using `java.sql.Statement#executeUpdate()` instead of `java.sql.Statement#execute()` for an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that there is no difference.

You will not find in any document about the Statement class that states that there is a performance difference between the two commands. Also as discussed in [OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=672225)  people agree that there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

The return value differs. `ExecuteUpdate()` returns the number of rows updated, which can be useful when running an update statement. but you  do not needed that one.So you can use any of them .Nothing you will get advantage.